# Separate component file with vue cdn

Tags: express, vue.js, cdn

I have an `express` server serving only one GET route and return the file `'public/app.html'`

This `app.html` file load vue.js throw cdn
`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js`

I don't want to have a big component!

How can I put every component in a different file?

What I tried:

I created a `/public/components/InputName.vue` vuejs component.

And inside `public/app.html` in `<script>` I added:

```
import InputName from './InputName'
```

But I have this error

```
import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

Comment: Talk some code with JSfiddle. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this GitHub Repo : 
it explains how you can load a component from a server: 
https://github.com/maoberlehner/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http